# Stripe - Get the LAST customer invoice

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there a way to filter the invoice result by the **last invoice** that was generated for a particular customer?

Going through the Stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming) I can see it is possible to get an upcoming invoice, but I can't find a way to get the last generated one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using stripe billing, then the `subscription` contains a [LatestInvoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-latest_invoice) - so you can either use the `latestInvoiceId`, or you can get the subscription and [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) it to also return the latest invoice in one hit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list

> The invoices are returned sorted by creation date, with the most recently created invoices appearing first.

So, if you want the most recent for a given customer

```
invoices = stripe.Invoice.list(customer="cus_xxxyyyzzz")
# first in the list should be the most recent
print(invoices.data[0])
```